# use viewpager instead of opening url with browser

Tags: android, android-intent, android-viewpager

I am creating News Reader app.

Here is part of code from MainActivity:

```
 newsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

            News currentNews = mAdapter.getItem(position);

            Uri newsUri = Uri.parse(currentNews.getUrl());

            Intent websiteIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, newsUri);

            startActivity(websiteIntent);
        }
    });
```

As you can see, it opens current item from List in Web Browser. Can I make it to open current item in View Pager?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Maybe you meant webView?

Comment: No, I need to show news even when there is no internet connection